# Tkinter, как использовать переменные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, tkinter, python-3.6

Хочу узнать как совершать математические операции над переменными с использованием библиотеки tkinter
т.е.:

```
#Наименование первой перменной

fourth = tkinter.Label (frame2, text='X')
fourth.pack(side='left')

#Считывание данных

xvar = tkinter.IntVar()
label = tkinter.Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame2,width=10, textvariable=xvar)
entry.pack(side='left')

#Вторая переменная

yvar = tkinter.Label (frame2, text='Y')
fifth.pack(side='left')

#Считывание данных

radius = tkinter.IntVar()
label = tkinter.Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame2,width=10, textvariable=yvar)
entry.pack(side='left')
```

Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы после того как мы открыли программу и написали в поля значения для переменных, мы могли сразу же(в режиме реального времени) видеть результат, допустим, такой операции как xvar*yvar (умножение)

```
frame3 = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame3.pack()
label = tkinter.Label(frame3, text=xvar*yvar )
label.pack()
```

В результате выдает ошибку:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'
Эту проблему я погуглил и решения заключаются, что с самими переменными надо что-то сделать при помощи

```
x.get() \ x.set()
```

Но принцип работы с ними я так и не понял.

Comment: Если бы названия переменных в разных фрагментах кода не были бы совершенно разными, то было бы проще понять вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def calc(s, x, y):
    s.set(x.get() + y.get())


x = IntVar()
y = IntVar()
s = IntVar()

root = Tk()

xvar = Entry(root, textvariable=x)
xvar.pack()

yvar = Entry(root, textvariable=y)
yvar.pack()

svar = Entry(root, textvariable=s)
svar.pack()

x.trace('w', lambda *args: calc(s, x, y))
y.trace('w', lambda *args: calc(s, x, y))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Так же вылазит
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/project/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = tkinter.IntVar()
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 499, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\miniconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 314, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: Попробуйте `x = IntVar(root)`