# TypeError: must be real number, not IntVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, tkinter, matplotlib

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая строит график полета мяча.

Я новичок и, конечно же, скопипастил часть кода из примера по созданию графика для синуса, но необходимую формулу вставил сам (y).

```
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Полет ядра')

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

frame2 = Frame(window, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
frame2.pack()

first = Label (frame, text='Данные')
first.pack(side='left')

second = Label (frame2, text='Начальная скорость')
second.pack(side='left')

v = IntVar()
label = Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=v)
entry.pack(side='left')

third = Label (frame2, text='Угол выстрела')
third.pack(side='left')

angle = IntVar()
label = Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=angle)
entry.pack(side='left')

fourth = Label (frame2, text='Начальная координата x')
fourth.pack(side='left')

x0 = IntVar()
label = Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=x0)
entry.pack(side='left')

fifth = Label (frame2, text='Начальная координата y')
fifth.pack(side='left')

y0 = IntVar()
label = Label(frame2)
label.pack(side='left')
entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=y0)
entry.pack(side='left')
g = 9.81

def func(x,v,g,y0,angle):
    y = x * tan(angle) - (1 / (2*v**2)) * ((g*x**2) / (cos(angle)**2)) + y0
    if y == 0:
        return 1.0
    return y


xmin = -20.0
xmax = 20.0

dx = 0.01

xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)

ylist = [func(x,v,g,y0,angle) for x in xlist]

pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)

pylab.show()

window.mainloop()
```

В результате выходит вот такая ошибка -

```
C:/Users/Максим/PycharmProjects/test/test.py:67: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: numpy.arange
  xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Максим/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 69, in <module>
    ylist = [func(x,v,g,y0,angle) for x in xlist]
  File "C:/Users/Максим/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
    ylist = [func(x,v,g,y0,angle) for x in xlist]
  File "C:/Users/Максим/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 56, in func
    y = x * tan(angle) - (1 / (2*v**2)) * ((g*x**2) / (cos(angle)**2)) + y0
TypeError: must be real number, not IntVar
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from tkinter import *

v = None
angle = None
x0 = None
y0 = None


def window():
    global v
    global angle
    global x0
    global y0
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Полет ядра')

    v = IntVar()
    angle = IntVar()
    x0 = IntVar()
    y0 = IntVar()

    frame = Frame(window)
    frame.pack()

    frame2 = Frame(window, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
    frame2.pack()

    first = Label (frame, text='Данные')
    first.pack(side='left')

    second = Label (frame2, text='Начальная скорость')
    second.pack(side='left')

    label = Label(frame2)
    label.pack(side='left')
    entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=v)
    entry.pack(side='left')

    third = Label (frame2, text='Угол выстрела')
    third.pack(side='left')

    label = Label(frame2)
    label.pack(side='left')
    entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=angle)
    entry.pack(side='left')

    fourth = Label (frame2, text='Начальная координата x')
    fourth.pack(side='left')

    label = Label(frame2)
    label.pack(side='left')
    entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=x0)
    entry.pack(side='left')

    fifth = Label (frame2, text='Начальная координата y')
    fifth.pack(side='left')

    label = Label(frame2)
    label.pack(side='left')
    entry = Entry(frame2, width=10, textvariable=y0)
    entry.pack(side='left')

    window.mainloop()


def func(x,v,g,y0,angle):
    y = x * tan(angle) - (1 / (2*v**2)) * ((g*x**2) / (cos(angle)**2)) + y0
    if y == 0:
        return 1.0
    return y

window()

v = v.get()
angle = angle.get()
x0 = x0.get()
y0 = y0.get()

xmin = -20.0
xmax = 20.0
g = 9.81
dx = 0.01

xlist = mlab.frange (xmin, xmax, dx)

ylist = [func(x,v,g,y0,angle) for x in xlist]

pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)

pylab.show()
```

Comment: А не получиться перенести график сразу в tkinter? При таком раскладе получается что сначала открывается tkinter, в него вписываются значения,а потом открывается сам график.

Answer (score 1):

```
ylist = [func(x, v.get(), g, y0.get(), angle.get()) for x in xlist]
```

Comment: `TypeError: must be real number, not IntVar`
Заменилось на -

   `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Comment: Значит в момент работы включения `v.get()` возвращает 0.

Comment: Переменным изначально не задано значение.
Только IntVar

Comment: Всё правильно, `IntVar` возвращает 0, если никакого другого значения ему не присваивалось.

Comment: Можно ли ввести значения переменным и после этого приравнять их к другим и последние уже использовать в функции для графика? 
`v = IntVar`
`new_v = v`
`...func(x,new_v,...`
Хотя, что-то мне подсказывает, что `new_v` унаследует `v`

Comment: Во-первых, можно задать значения по умолчанию для переменных, связанных с полями ввода. Во-вторых, перерисовывать график при вводе новых значений пользователей. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/899133/204271) можно почитать о том, как это сделать.